# Can't change AnchorPoint for CAShapeLayer iOS Swift

Tags: cashapelayer, anchorpoint, catransform3drotate

Here is extract from my custom class, that drawing some graphics. Function `drawTick()` adds `CAShapeLayer` with blue rectangle to my `GameTimer` `UIView`:

```
class GameTimer: UIView {

 var tick = CAShapeLayer()
...

 init(){
   super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
 }
...

 func drawTick() {
 tick.path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)).cgPath
 tick.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
 self.layer.addSublayer(tick)
 tick.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
 tick.position = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
 tick.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(0.degreesToRadians, 0, 0, 1)
 }

...

}

extension Double {
  var degreesToRadians : CGFloat {
      return CGFloat(self) * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0
  }
}
```

[image]

Changing of rotation angle to 45 degrees by

```
tick.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(45.degreesToRadians, 0, 0, 1)
```

gives the next result:

[image]

Here I see, that the declared anchor point doesn't affect the `tick` layer - it should be at the center of blue rect. The rotation goes around point with coordinates (x: 0, y: 0) - the left top corner of blue rect - `tick.position`.
The question - why declared `anchorPoint` position doesn't apply to the `tick` layer? It's behavior weird here assuming that the default position of `anchorPoint` should be already `(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)` without any manual override, but if I remove this override - nothing changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tick` layer doesn't have a size. The reason it looks correct is that the path isn't clipped to the bounds (i.e. is drawn outside the bounds).

If you give the shape layer the same `bounds` as the circle's rectangle, then you'll be able to see the rotation around the center.

Comment: Thanks! Works exactly as you're mentioned.

Comment: can you give an example